# ImageResize change image pixel value range

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a weird image in my notebook. If I do `ImageResize` to it. The pixel values of this image is changed.

[image]

Sorry, I can not share this image directly. As you can see, exporting it and then importing it back will not reproduce this behavior. So I have to share this notebook [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18HTVqCBJjObYLGpkSv730XmoP4_yjPEA/view?usp=sharing).

What is wrong with this image? How to correctly `ImageResize` this image without changing its pixel value (Of course, I can not stand exporting and importing)?

Comment: I don't see why you need to share the notebook file instead of **adding code as text** as is customary, and a link to the original image. I may be overly paranoid, but I still do not like opening potentially executable files from the internet.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your comment. I already said in the post if I share exported image, and then you import it. You will not reproduce the weird behavior.

Comment: @MarcoB By the way, will a Mathematica notebook run anything automatically when it is just opened without evaluating?

Comment: Potentially, if it contains dynamic evaluations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare `Information[img]` and `Information[Import["D:\\1.png"]]`. You will see that the data type of original image is `Real32`, while exporting/importing to .png make it `Bit16`.

You can either change the data type of your image:

```
ImageResize[Image[img, "Bit16"], 100] // MinMax
(* {0., 1.} *)
```

or use different resampling method for resizing (see documentation for [`ImageResize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html)):

```
ImageResize[img, 100, Resampling -> "Nearest"] // MinMax
(* {0., 1.} *)
```